# Instead of showing some modified files, Git shows all files in Solution as Added/Modified

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio for development. I am on my local branch and I was about to commit/push. In Git changes I had about 16 files which were modified. Now some reasons Git has listed all files in solution to Git Changes as File Added(New files). I ended up with 100+ files on my Git Changes.
I only want to push my changes which are on 16 files I mentioned and The project runs just fine.

I am little bit lost on what to do. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is **staging**. Before you commit, you can **stage** specific files. Then once the commit is executed, only modifications to those specific files will be part of the commit. I suspect what happened in your scenario is that you didn't specify what files to stage before committing, so Visual Studio assumed you wanted to commit everything.

This is easiest done via the command line (instructions for this [here](https://github.com/git-guides/git-add)), otherwise follow [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-make-commit?view=vs-2022) instructions to do this in Visual Studio.